# Question on Oauth2 Resource Owner Password Credential Grant in R httr

Tags: r, api, token

I use Oauth2 authorization to get the token for REST API. I tested the setting in SoapUI and it is working with the Resource Owner Password Credential Grant as shown below.

[The setting in the SoapUI testing is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDW4G.png)

Now, I want to retrieve the token through R httr library, but I don’t know how to set the resource owner name and password in the R code. Here is my Code

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- POST("https://XXXXXXX.com/authservice/connect/token",
          config = list(),
          body = list(
            
            # grant_type      = "RESOURCE_OWNER_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS",
            grant_type        = "resource_owner_credentials",
            
            resourceOwnerName         = "ResourceName",
            resourceOwnerPassword     = "Resourcepwd",
            
            # resource_Owner_Name     = "ResourceName",
            # resource_Owner_Password = "Resourcepwd",
            
            # resourceOwner_Name      = "ResourceName",
            # resourceOwner_Password  = "Resourcepwd",
            
            # resource_OwnerName      = "ResourceName",
            # resource_OwnerPassword  = "Resourcepwd",
            
            # resource_Name           = "ResourceName",
            # resource_Password       = "Resourcepwd",
            
            # resource_id             = "ResourceName",
            # resource_secret         = "Resourcepwd",
            
            client_id            = "ClientIDname",
            client_secret        = "Clientpassword",
            
            scope                = "xxxGroup"
          ),
          encode = "form"
)
warn_for_status(r)
content(r)
status_code(r)
```

I got a 400 error ("unsupported_grant_type" and bad request). I am guessing there may be something wrong with the syntax on the resource onwer name and password, so I also tried all the possible combinations that I commented in above code but they all failed.

My question is: are the parameter names for both resource owner name and password pre-defined by the API document, or they are the fixed names defined by R-httr librabry, regardless what token authorization service?

Can someone help to take a look at? Any input is greatly appreciate!

Comment: Try `grant_type = "password"`. I see you are using Resource Owner Password flow, the request parameter names are listed here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2 . Also, the other parameter names are `username` and `password`, not `resourceOwnerName` and `resourceOwnerPassword`.

Comment: Hi Jon,  your solution works!  Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it!